# How to configure HiveMQ client serverHost, serverPort & sslConfig for SSL connect to port 8883?

Tags: android, tls1.2, mosquitto, hivemq

Having read some docs and all examples I could find, I do not see a very simple example of connecting by SSL to 8883. It was very simple to create the HiveMQ client on Android to connect to the broker at mosquito.org, port 1883. But using credentials that I generated there, when trying to connect to port 8883 fails and this log message is seen:

```
MacAddressUtil com.example.tryhive W Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: f4:51:aa:f9:c6:c8:9d:fa
```

I am just following simple examples for client creation:

```
mqttClient = MqttClient.builder()
.useMqttVersion3()
.identifier(“MyID”)
.serverHost("test.mosquitto.org")
.serverPort(8883)
.sslConfig()
.keyManagerFactory(managers.kmf)
.trustManagerFactory(managers.tmf)
.applySslConfig()
.buildAsync()
```

The key manager and trust manager factories, built with the credentials created at mosquito.org work to make a TLS connection using the Paho MqttAndroidClient in a different Android app - should I post those here as well anyway?

I tried to use a similar serverHost as done with Paho client:

```
.serverHost("ssl://test.mosquitto.org")
.serverPort(8883)
```

But that results in an exception being thrown in Netty.

Also interesting to note is that when I first ran the non-secure client, I inadvertently left in the uri used with Paho Client, so this:

```
.serverHost(“tcp://test.mosquitto.org”)
.serverPort(1883)
```

And that as well caused the connection to fail with the same MacAddressUtil log above:

```
MacAddressUtil com.example.tryhive W Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: f4:51:aa:f9:c6:c8:9d:fa
```

That is why I didn’t clutter this post with the code that creates the Key and Trust Manager Factories passed to the sslConfig() - it seems that the error is somewhere else.

Please share any sample code that works for you or lessons you learned wrt this using HiveMQ yourself.

Update 2022/12/05:
Suspecting an issue in Netty, I've tried using their latest release to no avail:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.hivemq:hivemq-mqtt-client:1.3.0'
    implementation(platform("io.netty:netty-bom:4.1.85.Final"))
```

Still cannot connect with HiveMQ client to any mosquitto secure ports: 8883, 8884, or 8885.

So I tried to go in through the websocket interface with this:

```
    implementation 'com.hivemq:hivemq-mqtt-client-websocket:1.3.0'
```

and of course adding to the MqttClient.builder():

```
.webSocketWithDefaultConfig()
```

Then it connects without .sslConfig() to mosquitoo port 8080
But then enabling SSL, connections fail to ports 8081, 8090 & 8091

I know that this seems to point more to an error in my implementation of the KeyManagerFactory and/or the TrustManagerFactory, but the identical code to build them is used in an app that uses the Paho client, and secure connection succeeds.

Comment: The `W` in the message about not being able to find usable hardware means it's a warning not an error. This is likely to be a red herring and unrelated to the real problem. Second `serverHost()` takes just a hostname, not a URI

Comment: Thanks. WRT serverHost(), for sure I am using .serverHost("test.mosquitto.org")

I mentioned having failed to not connect to 1883 by inadvertently leaving in the config used for Paho client only to share the fact that that triggered the same W log message.

Which is to say, thanks for seconding my hunch that the MacAddressUtil log is a red herring.